# Examples of UI heavy Object Oriented Javascript apps

Tags: javascript, oop

I'm fairly new developer who's been using Javascript in procedural way for nearly a year. In the company I'm working, we develop UI rich web apps with lots of interactions (dropdowns, sliders, modals, animations). I've noticed, that when project gets bigger it turns out to unmaintainable mess.

I've come to conclusion that it would be great to start developing apps in object oriented way, but I cannot find any good tutorials on how to do it. All I can find is some basic examples with Cat extending Animal object and so on.

I'd like to ask you for some github links to open source projects with lots of UI elements which uses Object Oriented Javascript. That way I can get a grasp of how it's supposed to be done correctly. Also it would be ideal, if it was pre ES6 as our projects are written in ES5.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi Mateusz, welcome to Stack Overflow! As per our forum rules, questions asking for external resources such as tutorials are **off topic**, so I'll have to flag your question to be closed. Please check the [FAQ] and [ask].

Comment: Start with putting your procedural code, and the state that it manipulates, in objects (as methods and data properties). Use simple object literals for that. Nothing else is needed for OOP.